# Django 1.8 app mysteriously fails with initial migration due to errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-migrations

I'm writing an app in django 1.8 with python 3.4 and I'm encountering an issue with using MySQL as the database backend which has got me completely stumped.

When I start off with a new database and call ./manage.py migrate (or syncdb) and it tries to create the initial database, I get the following traceback:

```
(virtualenv)~/projects/projmoj (master ✘)✹✭ ᐅ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: allauth, rest_framework, registration, rest_auth, projmoj, messages, project, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, sites, sessions, task, auth, admin, authtoken, static_precompiler, account
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table project_project
    Creating table project_membership
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 220, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 371, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/tobbe/projects/projmoj/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `tasks`.`#sql-1c32_9` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
```

This error happens when I do the same on a web hosting service, it works however using sqlite on both the hosting service and localhost.

I have no migrations, and these are my models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 32) 
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def get_owner(self):
    return self.members.filter(status=OWNER).first().user

  def get_membership(self, user):
    return self.members.filter(user=user).first()

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + " - by " + str(self.get_owner().username)

class Membership(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='joined_projects')
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='members')
  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=MEMBER_STATUS)
  join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)

class Sprint(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null=True, blank=True)
  start_date = models.DateTimeField()
  due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='sprints')
  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SPRINT_STATUS, default=PLANNING)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + " - " + str(self.project)

class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 32) 
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='categories')

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + " - " + str(self.project)

class Goal(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 32) 
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='goals')
  completion = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=COMPLETION, default=NOT_COMPLETED)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + " - " + str(self.project)

class Task(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='tasks')
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tasks', null=True, blank=True)
  goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, related_name='tasks', null=True, blank=True)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, related_name='tasks', null=True, blank=True)
  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TASK_STATUS, default=WAITING)
  dedicated_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
  assigned_worker = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
  priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY, default=NORMAL)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name) + " - " + str(self.project)

class HourReport(models.Model):
  task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='hour_reports')
  worker = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='hour_reports')
  hours_spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.hours_spent) + " on " + str(self.task)
```

My database settings:

```
DATABASES = { 
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'tasks',
      'USER': 'root',
      'PASSWORD': 'mysqlmysql',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
  }
}
```

Versions etc:

- Django 1.8
- Python 3.4
- Default storage engine: InnoDB
- Mysqlclient 1.3.6
- Server: MySQL 5.5.42 on Amazon RDS (at web hosting)
- Server: 10.0.21-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server (localhost)

When googling it seems like this error is often when people stuff up their manual SQL code, but I am doing it all automatically through django.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have all apps with migrations? You have two FKs on membership and I don't see user...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177651/why-this-database-migration-error-after-i-upgrade-my-version-django-mptt

Comment: @Alasdair I import the user with 'from django.contrib.auth.models import User' so I'm not using any custom user.

Comment: @GlynJackson Hmm, what do you mean? One of the apps does not have migrations, but that is because I have not changed anything.

Comment: Do you include User in your app settings?

Comment: @GlynJackson No, since I want the default one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The log is telling you that you have not created migrations for your `project` app. You should create migrations for the app before running migrate.

```
./manage.py makemigrations project
./manage.py migrate
```

Since it's a new database, you'd be better to completely reset it before creating and applying the migrations, otherwise you'll have to manually deal with its current inconsistent state.

Comment: Thanks! I had no unapplied migrations so makemigrations didn't do anything (detects no changes), but migrating 'sites' and then 'auth' explicitly and then doing the standard migrate worked! I guess I still don't know why the problem arose but thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I still think the log suggests that there are no migrations for the project app. Maybe specifically doing `manage.py make migrations project` would work.

Comment: Well, there we go, that did add the migrations for that app. I guess I must have done something to make it not create them automatically. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Django documentation [MySQL notes. Storage engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#storage-engines)

> If you upgrade an existing project to `MySQL 5.5.5` and subsequently
>   add some tables, ensure that your tables are using the same storage
>   engine (i.e. `MyISAM` vs. `InnoDB`). Specifically, if tables that have
>   a `ForeignKey` between them use different storage engines, you may see
>   an error like the following when running `migrate`:
>
> ```
>  _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (
>     1005, "Can't create table '\\db_name\\.#sql-4a8_ab' (errno: 150)"
>  )
> ```

Stop you backend and do backup. Than change storage engine for tables from MyISAM to InnoDB. It's fix the problem.

Also in the MySQL docs (
[B.3 Server Error Codes and Messages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html) chapter) specified about this error:

> Error: 1005 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)
>
> Message: Can't create table '%s' (errno: %d - %s)
>
> InnoDB reports this error when a table cannot be created. If the error
>   message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign
>   key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers
>   to error −1, table creation probably failed because the table includes
>   a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible when running python `manage.py migrate` to get that error of

> _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table > `codelabs`.`django_admin_log` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

due to having wrong information in settings.py regarding the DATABASES. For instances, if in your database your table has the name *tiago**p**eres* and in your settings.py you're refering the NAME to be *tiago**P**eres*, that error will show up. To fix it, just use the correct NAME and run again `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of the command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` in MySql or MariaDB console client ([mariadb link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-engine-innodb-status/), [mysql link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html)). It`s more informative.
For example, it showed me this message:

```
...
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2021-09-20 18:27:08 7faea3ad1700 Error in foreign key constraint of table `my_db`.`django_admin_log`:
Alter  table `my_db`.`django_admin_log` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `my_db`.`profiles_userprofile` not found in the data dictionary near ' FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `profiles_userprofile` (`id`)'.
...
```

It said to me that I forgot to create migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because existing tables had been created with MyISAM as the SQL Engine but the most recent migration was InnoDB.
(using MariaDB 10.6.17)

I didn't want to lose thousands of rows of data, so I used this answer to generate the statements to ALTER the engine on all tables to InnoDB

[How to convert all tables from MyISAM into InnoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb)

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into this issue today and read articles and StackOverflow which didn't solve the issue.
Then I deleted my database as there was nothing special and removed all migration files and started the migration process again.
Issue solved.